# Parse a string using ANTLR4

Tags: antlr4

Example: (CHGA/B234A/B231

```
String:
        a) Designator: 3 LETTERS
        b) Message number (OPTIONAL): 1 to 4 LETTERS, followed by A SLASH (/) followed by 1 to 4 LETTERS, followed by 3 NUMBERS indicating the serial number.
        c) Reference data (OPTIONAL): 1 to 4 LETTERS, followed by A SLASH (/) followed by 1 to 4 LETTERS, followed by 3 NUMBERS indicating the serial number.

Result: 
 CHG
 A/B234
 A/B231
```

In grammar file:

```
/*
 * Parser Rules
 */

tipo3: designador idmensaje? idmensaje?;
designador: PARENTHESIS CHG;
idmensaje: LETTER4 SLASH LETTER4 DIGIT3;

/*
 * Lexer Rules
 */

CHG     : 'CHG' ;

fragment DIGIT      : [0-9] ;
fragment LETTER     : [a-zA-Z] ;

SLASH               : '/' ;
PARENTHESIS         : '(' ;

DIGIT3              : DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT ;
LETTER4             : LETTER LETTER? LETTER? LETTER? ;
```

But when testing the `tipo3` rule its giving me the following message:

> line 1:1 missing 'CHG' at 'CHGA'

How can i parse that string in antlr4?

Comment: Please post a complete grammar that (tries to) parse the input in your question. The grammar from your question is just a couple of rules, that by no means cover the example input.

Comment: I'm currently learning antlr and I don't know what's wrong or what's missing to parse the string. in the IDE I can test each rule of the parser and in this case when I test the rule `tipo3` it shows the message posted and i don't how to fixed

Comment: Ah, you're feeding it the input `"(CHGA/B234A/B231"`, not the part beneath it `"String: a) Designator: ..."`. I now see that `String: ...` part is an explanation of your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're confused why a certain parser rule is not being matched, always start with the lexer. Dump what tokens your lexer is producing on the stdout. Here's how you can do that:

```java
// I've placed your grammar in a file called T.g4 (hence the name `TLexer`)
String source = "(CHGA/B234A/B231";
TLexer lexer = new TLexer(CharStreams.fromString(source));
CommonTokenStream stream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
stream.fill();

for (Token t : stream.getTokens()) {
  System.out.printf("%-20s `%s`%n",
      TLexer.VOCABULARY.getSymbolicName(t.getType()),
      t.getText().replace("\n", "\\n"));
}
```

If you runt the Java code above, this will be printed:

```
PARENTHESIS          `(`
LETTER4              `CHGA`
SLASH                `/`
LETTER4              `B`
DIGIT3               `234`
LETTER4              `A`
SLASH                `/`
LETTER4              `B`
DIGIT3               `231`
EOF                  `<EOF>`
```

As you can see, `CHGA` becomes a single `LETTER4`, not a `CHG` + `LETTER4` token. Try changing `LETTER4` into `LETTER4 : LETTER;` and re-test. Now you'll get the expected result.

In your current grammar `CHGA` will always become a single `LETTER4`. This is just how ANTLR works (the lexer tries to consume as many chars for a single rule as possible). You cannot change this.

What you could do, it move the construction of the multi-letter rule to the parser instead of the lexer:

```
tipo3       : designador idmensaje? idmensaje?;
designador  : PARENTHESIS CHG;
idmensaje   : letter4 SLASH letter4 DIGIT3;
letter4     : LETTER LETTER? LETTER? LETTER?
            | CHG
            ;

CHG         : 'CHG' ;
LETTER      : [a-zA-Z] ;
SLASH       : '/';
PARENTHESIS : '(';
DIGIT3      : DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT;

fragment DIGIT : [0-9];
```

resulting in:

[image]